# Lyapunov differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I come across a matrix differential equation which is similar to the Lyapunov differential equation, that is

\begin{equation}
\frac{d A(t)}{d t} = M(t)A^\top(t) + A^\top(t)M(t) + R(t), \quad A(0) = A_0
\end{equation}

where $A(t), M(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. I am wondering how to solve this matrix ODE. Can someone give me some hints?

Thanks!

Comment: You could always convert the matrix $A(t)$ into a vector $a(t)\in \mathbb{R}^{m^{2}}$.

Comment: You mean by Kronecker product? But the right hand side is $vec(A^\top)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple example where $m=2$ but can be generalized to any $m$. I will drop the $(t)$ just to ease notation and use $\dot{a} = \frac{d a}{d t}$. The dynamics when $m=2$ is,

\begin{align}
\frac{d A}{dt} = \begin{bmatrix}\dot{a}_{11} & \dot{a}_{12} \\ \dot{a}_{21} & \dot{a}_{22}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{21} \\ a_{12} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{21} \\ a_{12} & a_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}r_{11} & r_{12} \\ r_{21} & r_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Notice that we can convert the matrix $A$ into a vector $a$ with the same dynamics.

Let $a=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} \\ a_{12} \\ a_{21} \\ a_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ then the matrix dynamics can be written as,

\begin{align}
\dot{a} = \begin{bmatrix}\dot{a}_{11} \\ \dot{a}_{12} \\ \dot{a}_{21} \\ \dot{a}_{22}\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{21} & 0 \\
m_{12} & 0 & m_{11}+m_{22}  & m_{12} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} + m_{11} & 0 & m_{21} \\
0 & m_{12} & m_{21} & 2m_{22} \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}a_{11} \\ a_{12} \\ a_{21} \\ a_{22}\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}r_{11} \\ r_{12} \\ r_{21} \\ r_{22}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

which is just a linear time-varying system.